# How to add photo to iPhone from desktop?

Tags: c#, synchronization, photo

Recently, i want to create an application to sync photos between iphone and desktop by using C# language. I use Manzana library to copy image from PC to iphone.

As my understanding, the image file should be put under to /private/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Sync folder. But this does not work, i cannot see imported file when browse iphone photos although the file is copy to the location correctly.

Then i try to update the database file /private/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite. To add a new entry to represent the imported photo file. Then i can see photo in iphone, but without thumbnails. And i have to restart the album application (close the application and start it again) so that to see the new imported photo.

But i found other tools can sync photo to iphone and can see the change immediately without restart the album application.

I want to know how this function is implemented?

Manzana is a C# wrapper of iTunesMobileDevice.dll.  the main functionality is deal with iphone file system. and this is quite a old library which is not updated for a long time. I am not sure if there are any APIs to allow user to select an folder or photo file and sync it to iphone just like we do it in itunes, so that we don't need to process the db and thumbnails.

Does anyone have such experience before?

Comment: I just want to know how other tools to do such work. Such as iFunBox. I think they also call the function provided by itunes, but not know how to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Im using desktop Dropbox as a buffer between mobile app and desktop.
2. Before this, you need a DropBox registered account and install the application.
3. After that, simple create a new folder from desktop Dropbox, drag-and-drop all
   your photos into the new folder
4. Then, return to your iphone and retrieve them from DropBox mobile app.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, but this is not i wanted. And other tools seems can copy photo to iphone without install an APP into iphone. Any solution to implement without an app into iphone?